# publishing an application made with MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, mono, release, publish

I just created a small application in MonoDevelop (on a windows machine). Now I want to test this on different platforms, but I can not figure how to publish the application.

I want an installer for windows, ubuntu and mac.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [official porting guide](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3a_Porting_Winforms_Applications) for help with linux.   I assume it'd be similar for a mac, but I couldn't gurantee it, since MonoMac is a separate variation of Mono.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but I am looking for a way to create installers. I already have the project, which should run on different systems.

Comment: @user1622277 - Well, I know when you build a MonoMac project, it gives you an executable you can just drag-and-drop to a Mac.  Couldn't tell you about the other systems, though.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac, there is [MacPack](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications#macpack_.28Mac_OS_X_only.29).

For Linux, installer or bundle is generally not the way to go. You would probably create a distribution *package*. You have to search for something specific to packaging system of a given distribution, [here](http://weblog.savanne.be/jo-shields.odp) is some source for Debian. Nonetheless you can create such executable (naturally, it will be architecture specific), read about it [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications#Bundles).

For Windows, you can for example use [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/).